# Error al querer mostrar un valor NSNumber como Integer en una string

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Tengo lo siguiente y me tira un error incompatible integer to pointer...

```
int *v = [numero intValue];
NSLog(@"Numero %d",v);
```

Donde numero es un `NSNumber`.
¿Como se haria para imprimir un `int`? ¿Y un `NSInteger`?

Comment: como esta declarado numero?

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar el error completo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entiendo que `numero` está declarado como `NSNumber` con algo de este estilo:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber  *numero;
```

Y lo que quieres es asignarlo a `i` que es un `int`.

El problema esta en que `NSNumber` es un objeto y la variable `i` es un `int` que es un tipo primitivo. Esto significa que `numero` será un puntero a algún sitio de la memoria, por eso lo del `*` en la declaración, pero `i` no es un objeto, así que no necesita el `*` en la declaración.

Si haces esto te funcionará correctamente:

```
int i = [self.numero integerValue];
NSLog(@"numero %d", i);
```

Comment: Ok, gracias funciona